# How to add a second network interface to an Azure Virtual Machine Scale Set?

Tags: azure, powershell, nic

I'm trying to add a second network interface with Windows PowerShell to a Microsoft Azure Virtual Machine Scale Set (VMSS). The VMSS already exists.

I am using Powershell since the az cli does not yet support adding network interfaces.

But my code seems not to work, since the network interface does not come up in the virtual machine.

I am referencing to code from http://thebluenode.com/azure-virtual-machine-scale-set-instances-upgrade-with-zero-downtime-rolling-update .

Please see my Powershell code what I am doing wrong. I guess I have to add some private IP configuration, but I don't know where.

Can you help me how to add a second network interface to my VMSS?

Thanks in advance.

Best regards,

Ronny Forberger

Tried the Powershell code provided.

```
Add-AzureRmAccount

Select-AzureRmSubscription -SubscriptionId "XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX"


$vnetname = "conf-virtual-network-interlink"

$loc = "West Europe"

$backendSubnetName = "default"

$backendSubnetConfig = New-AzureRmVirtualNetworkSubnetConfig -Name $backendSubnetName -AddressPrefix "10.1.0.0/24"

echo "backendSubnetConfig: "$backendSubnetConfig

$vnet = New-AzureRmVirtualNetwork -ResourceName $vnetname -Location $loc -ResourceGroupName "resourcegroup-confluence-jira-datacenter" -Subnet $backendSubnetConfig -AddressPrefix "10.1.0.0/24"

echo "vnet: "$vnet

$subnetId = (Get-AzureRmVirtualNetworkSubnetConfig -Name $backendSubnetName -VirtualNetwork $vnet).Id

echo "subnetId: "$subnetId

$ipCfg = New-AzureRmVmssIPConfig -Name 'eth1' -SubnetId $subnetId 

echo "ipCfg: "$ipCfg

$backendSubnet = Get-AzureRmVirtualNetworkSubnetConfig -Name $backendSubnetName -VirtualNetwork $vnet

echo "backendSubnet: "$backendSubnet

$vmss = Get-AzureRmVmss -ResourceGroupName resourcegroup-confluence-jira-datacenter -VMScaleSetName confcluster

echo "vmss: "$vmss

Add-AzureRmVmssNetworkInterfaceConfiguration -Name $backendSubnet -Primary $false -IPConfiguration $ipCfg -VirtualMachineScaleSet $vmss
```

Expected result is, that the network adapter in the VM of the VMSS comes up (ideally with a configured private IP).

Comment: Do you try to update the vmss?

Comment: @CharlesXu I am not sure. How do I do that?

Comment: Use the command Update-AzVmss or update the instance.

Comment: Hi @CharlesXu, thanks for your suggestion. The command Update-AzVmss is not installed on my system, I have tried installing and importing it using Install-Module -Name Az.Compute -AllowClobber and Import-Module Az.Compute, since the command seems to be provided by the module Az.Compute.

My problem is that I cannot install Az and AzureRm at the same time on the machine.

Error message:

WARNUNG: Both Az and AzureRM modules were detected on this machine. Az and AzureRM modules cannot be imported in the
same session or used in the same script or runbook. If you are running PowerShell..

Comment: You can also use the PowerShell command Update-AzureRmVmss while the Az module is recommended and the new version.

Comment: @CharlesXu Thanks, I used Update-AzureRmVmss. But now I'm getting the error Update-AzureRmVmss : VM scale set [...]/confcluster cannot reference subnets [...]/confclustersubnet,[...]/default from different virtual networks.
ErrorCode: VMScaleSetCannotReferenceSubnetsFromDifferentVirtualNetworks
But this is what I want, two different virtual networks with each two different subnets. Any idea whats going wrong?

Answer (score 1):

It's not possible to have different network adapters in different virtual networks. they have to be on the same virtual network, they can be on a different subnet in the same virtual network

Answer (score 0):

@RonnyForberger According to the [article](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/virtual-machine-scale-sets/virtual-machine-scale-sets-networking#multiple-nics-per-virtual-machine) -

*You can have up to 8 NICs per virtual machine, depending on machine size. The maximum number of NICs per machine is available in the [VM size](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/virtual-machines/windows/sizes) article. All NICs connected to a VM instance must connect to the same virtual network. The NICs can connect to different subnets, but all subnets must be part of the same virtual network.*

Please make sure you use the same virtual network to create a new NIC configuration for your VMSS. Also, if you don't mention any public IP configurations, the NIC will be assigned a private IP by default.

The script you are using should ideally work, provided the above conditions are met.

You can use the below command to list the NICs in the portal cloud shell:

```
az vmss nic list --resource-group amgar-resource-group --vmss-name nt1
```

Answer (score 0):

Had a similar ask.. tried your script, works well. You just have to run below commandlet once your vmss object is modified to have additional secondary NIC.

```
Update-AzureRmVmss -ResourceGroupName "resourcegroup-confluence-jira-datacenter" -Name "confcluster" -VirtualMachineScaleSet $vmss
```